# Convergence in distribution of a sequence indexed by a random variable

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, convergence

Let $(X_n(\theta))_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of random variables with value in $\mathbb{R}^q$ indexed by a parameter $\theta \in \Theta \subset \mathbb{R}^q$. Suppose that for all $\theta \in \Theta$:
\begin{align*}
X_n(\theta) \longrightarrow \mathcal{N}(0,1) \quad \text{($\star$)}
\end{align*}
in distribution as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Now let $\nu$ be a probability measure such that $\nu(\Theta) = 1$. If we let $\theta \sim \nu$, does ($\star$) still hold?

Comment: What does $(*)$ even mean when you let $\theta$ be random?  You seem to be mixing up incompatible ideas. Are you positing that some property $(*)$ holds for every element of a probability space and then asking whether that property continues to hold?

Comment: @whuber yes. What I mean is that I draw $\theta \sim \nu$ then I draw the variables $X_1(\theta),X_2(\theta),\dots$ conditional on $\theta$. For instance let $X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(1/n,\theta^2)$ for some $\theta>0$, then $X_n/\theta$ converges in distribution to a standard gaussian for all fixed $\theta$. Now, let $\theta$ be a positive random variable and let $X_n | \theta \sim \mathcal{N}(1/n,\theta^2) $. Do we still have that $X_n/\theta$ convergs in distribution to a standard gaussian?

Comment: @Xi'an yes that's right.

Comment: Why might the truth or falsity of a universal statement about *all* values of a parameter possibly depend on whether a particular value was chosen randomly or not?

Comment: @whuber because there is something I don't really understand, hence my question. Do you mean my question has a trivial answer?

Comment: @Xi'an I'm sorry I don't get it. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: For $\theta\in\Theta,$ let $P(\theta)$ be the proposition that $X_n(\theta)\to\mathcal{N}(0,1).$ You assume $P(\theta)$ is true for all $\theta$ and then you *seem* to ask whether $P(\theta)$ is true if $\theta$ is chosen randomly from $\Theta.$ If so, I hope it's clear the answer is obvious: so where am I misinterpreting the question?

Comment: @whuber this is indeed what I'm asking. Can you help me see why the statement is obvious?

Comment: Yes: replace $P$ by any other proposition. Take, say, $\Theta$ to be the positive real numbers and let $P(\theta): \theta \gt 0,$ which is true everywhere.  You ask, "if I choose a number $\theta$ randomly from $\Theta,$ is $P(\theta)$ true?"  In short, "is a random positive number positive?"  Obviously yes.  *There is no logical difference between this question and yours.*

Comment: @whuber thanks!  I get it now

Comment: @Xi'an That indicates you see some difference between my positive-reals example and this one--but what exactly would it be?? Specifically, let's say that a parameter $\theta\in\Theta$ is "$\mathcal{P}$-positive" when $X_n(\theta)\to\mathcal{N}(0,1).$  Assuming all $\theta$ are $\mathcal{P}$-positive, is a random $\theta$ $\mathcal{P}$-positive?

Comment: @Xi'an - $\theta$ would appear to be fixed over all $n$, so there's no convergence issue that I can see.

Comment: @whuber: a proof based on the characteristic function ended up convincing me.